# Best way to make a newsletter slideshow kiosk for the office?

Tags: powerpoint, slideshow, kiosk

So, I've been tasked with making a kiosk for the office for showing statistics about our SCRUM progress, build server status, rentability and so forth. It should ideally run a slideshow with bunch of different pages, some of them showing text, some showing graphs and so on.

What is the best approach for this? I first thought of powerpoint, but It should be able to take the images from a webserver so I can automate the graph generation procedure. I would also like to take text from an external source when showing "Who broke the build" or some page like that.

I have no doubt that ready-made systems exist, but I don't really know where to look for them.

Is this easy/hard in powerpoint? Or are there an ubiquous app that everybody but me knows about?

Comment: To clarify, you are looking for a digital version of the Big Visible Wall?

Comment: Yes and no. We use a physical wall for the team itself, but to give a rehash to everyone in the office of what we are doing and how the company is doing, we want this to just boil down the facts and show them in an easy to understand way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend creating it as a series of web-pages, which uses Javascript or the meta refresh tag to cycle though the different pages. Simply full-screen the browser on a spare machine, and connect it to a projector/monitor/big TV.

This has lots of benefits:

- it's *trivial* to display images from an external server (an `<img>` tag)
- it will cost nothing to setup (it can run on basically any functioning machine), and runs in a browser
- it is quick to do (you do not have to worry about cross-browser compatibility, or different screen resolutions as you know the exact machine you are developing for
- it's expandable - while what you describe is probably possible within Powerpoint, but if you do it as a web-page, you can use Javascript (or a JS framework like jQuery), and it's very easy to serve the pages via a web-server, then you can use any server-side scripting language.

Basically, you would have a series of files, say `slide001.htm`, `slide002.htm` and `slide003.htm`. Slide 1 would redirect to slide002 after 30 seconds, slide002 to slide 003, and slide003 would redirect to slide001..

The specific things you mention: graph generation and "Who broke the build" text:

Not sure which CI tool you use, but many of them generate graphs anyway, so that would be required is having one "slide" with something like `<img src="http://hudson.abc/job/proj042/buildTimeGraph">`

For the who-broke-the-build text, you would be easiest to run the slides as `.php` files served though a web-server, using [XAMMP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

Then you would have a function that scrapes your CI server for whoever broke the last build, and in one of the slides, you would have `<?PHP echo(who_broke_build()); ?>`

(Obviously if you know some other language/system better, use that!)

The final benefit I can think of is that, if you serve the files through a web-server, you can allow people display it locally, say as their browsers home-page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I found jqS5 which did most of what you mentioned.

It requires 1 document where every h2 becomes a new slide.
I can then use the meta-refresh to reload to next page every 10 seconds. When I reach the end of the slides, I pull data from an aggregated RSS feed from all the different systems in order to pull information.

http://staticfree.info/projects/jqs5/